# What to do with this question?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056754/unity3d-vuforia-ar-camera-running-with-native-ios-app

I'm not sure if this question is completely on- or completely off- for Stackoverflow.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If they added code it'd be on-topic IMO. As it stands it's too broad.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I don't know about that. It looks on topic to me, considering he's asking for a very specific desired behavior.

Comment: @Magisch I have no strong feelings one way or the other. I know nothing about the technologies in question and as such have no idea how answerable it is in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No specific code means is either "unclear what you're asking" or "offtopic -> why isn't this code working". In its current form it will quickly attract close votes.

Comment: You might re-assess the post, as it was just updated.

Comment: not that it matters, but the code just added is a case of "Here's some code I found somewhere, so that I can tick the box of including code in an SO question" heh

Comment: Hi Oleg, I guess that's the size of it - thanks for that.